# Will I be banned if I use mods in terraria?

Tags: steam, terraria

I have Terraria on steam and I wish to play tremor mod with my friend on host & play, so my question is:

Can I use mods on Terraria without getting banned on steam or lose my terraria account?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Terraria modding community is well-established. You won't lose your account for using (non-cheating) mods in Terraria.

Comment: Even if you do use cheat mods, your Steam/GOG account is safe. There's no VAC or anything like that for Terraria. However, if you use the cheat mods on a server, the server owners might ban you from that one particular server.

Answer (score 3):

Terraria has no anti-cheat features, nor even have accounts.

Steam will not care/detect whether you cheated or not.

Terraria doesn't even have accounts for you to get banned with.

There are zero risks.

I've backed-up my save game to clone items and materials plenty of times.